# next.js webpack issue after module-federation update to v 7.0.8

Tags: next.js, webpack-module-federation, module-federationnextjs-mfutils

i use next.js 12.3.1,
"@next/bundle-analyzer": "^12.3.0",
"@module-federation/nextjs-mf@^6.0.4"  update to "@module-federation/nextjs-mf@^7.0.8" .

after yarn install and update, in yarn.lock mf dependencies it's happened and update to :

"@module-federation/node" "1.0.7" ,
"@module-federation/utilities" "2.0.6" ,
dependencies:
webpack-sources "3.2.3"

but in dev mode always get this error after chnage route

error = /node_modules/@module-federation/nextjs-mf/src/default-delegate.js?remote=videoPlayer@URL/_next/static/chunks/videoPlayer.js
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'updateHash')

i think webpack not well work and some routes not changed!

for build time errors we increases memory heap to 4096
Clean Yarn Cache: yarn cache clean
Reinstall Dependencies : yarn install